# Conditional rendering not working as intended - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to make a web application which fetches product/data from backend API and displays it into frontend and I'm also trying to implement add to cart and remove from cart functionality, I want to have it so that it shows 'add to cart' when the product is not in cart and 'remove from cart' when product is in their cart. Remove from cart functionality and conditional rendering is not working. It just stays at 'Add to cart' and when I click on add to cart. It does get added to cart. Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import axios from 'axios'


function HomeScreen() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
    const [oof, setOof] = useState()
    async function handleClick(id) {
        try{
           const chosen_product = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/products/${id}`)
           const newCart = cart.concat(chosen_product);
           setCart(newCart);
           localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(newCart));
        }
        catch(error){
         // error-handling goes here
        }
      }
      async function removeCart(id) {
        try{
           let newCart;
           cart.map((productId, index)=> {
               if (productId.id == id) {
                newCart = cart.slice(index)
               }
           })
           setCart(newCart);
           localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(newCart));
        }
        catch(error){
         // error-handling goes here
        }
      }
    useEffect(() => {
        async function getProducts() {
            try {
              const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/products/');
              setProducts(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
              console.error(error);
            }
          }
       getProducts()
    },[])

    return (
        <div>
            {products.map(product => {
               
                return (
                <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded" key={product.id}>
            <Card.Img src={'http://localhost:8000' + product.image} />
            <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title as="div">
                <strong>{product.name}</strong>
            </Card.Title>
            <Card.Text as="div">
            
            </Card.Text>
            <Card.Text as="h3">
            ${product.price}
            </Card.Text>
            <Card.Link>
            {cart.some(cartProduct=>cartProduct.id==product.id)
              ?(<Button onClick={()=>removeCart(product.id)} className="btn- 
                primary">Remove from cart</Button>)
              : (<Button onClick={()=>handleClick(product.id)} className="btn- 
                primary">Add to cart</Button>)
            }
            </Card.Link>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: What instead gets displayed ? Can you add that to your question ?

Comment: 'Add to cart' button gets displayed if product is not in user's cart and 'Remove from cart' button gets displayed if it is in user's cart

Comment: That's the behaviour you want. I am asking what's the current unexpected behaviour ? What's the UI output you get ? Add that to question instead of comments.

Comment: The buttons are not showing up at all

Comment: Because your cart is empty. Map through an empty array will return notthing so the button will not appear.

Comment: Your code will not work when `cart` is empty which it will be initially.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not work when cart is empty which it will be initially. Also `.map` isn't what you require here. You only want to check the existence of the `product` in your `cart` by the means of unique identifier `id`. `some` will return `true` as soon as it finds it and else return `false`.

```
            {cart.some(cartProduct=>cartProduct.id===product.id)
              ?(<Button onClick={()=>removeCart(product.id)} className="btn- 
                primary">Remove from cart</Button>)
              : <Button onClick={()=>handleClick(product.id)} className="btn- 
                primary">Add to cart</Button>)
            }
```

Comment: This does not work, Only 'Add to cart' appears

Comment: Is each item in your `cart` , a product object or just the product id ?. The above should have worked.  Also I have done `===` comparison which is strict. Will not work if one place `id` is string and in another a number.

Comment: I used ```==``` and it still does not work, Thanks for your answer tho

Comment: Just log the contents of `cart` state before `return` statement. Check if your item is even getting added as it should be post API call.

Comment: API is not involved in this, I'm trying to store this in browser's localstorage

Comment: `await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/products/${id}`)` - That's an API call.

Comment: Yeah, That is only to see the object and to store it and it works perfectly fine and it is GET request.

Answer (score 0):

instead of map() use find() on your cart state:

```
{cart.find(({ id }) => id === product.id)
    ? <Button onClick={()=>removeCart(product.id)} className="btn-primary">Remove from cart</Button>
    : <Button onClick={()=>handleClick(product.id)} className="btn-primary">Add to cart</Button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
        {products.length?products.map(product => {
           
            return (
            <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded" key={product.id}>
        <Card.Img src={'http://localhost:8000' + product.image} />
        <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title as="div">
            <strong>{product.name}</strong>
        </Card.Title>
        <Card.Text as="div">
        
        </Card.Text>
        <Card.Text as="h3">
        ${product.price}
        </Card.Text>
        <Card.Link>
        {cart.some(cartProduct=>cartProduct.id==product.id)
          ?(<Button onClick={()=>removeCart(product.id)} className="btn- 
            primary">Remove from cart</Button>)
          : (<Button onClick={()=>handleClick(product.id)} className="btn- 
            primary">Add to cart</Button>)
        }
        </Card.Link>
        </Card.Body>
    </Card>
            )
        }):null}
    </div>
```

try this it will work